# what is the difference between presenter in mvp and view-model in mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-mvp, android-mvvm

I need to clear some of my doubts regarding mvp and mvvm design pattern

1) In mvp and mvvm who updates the view .The presenter/view-model set the 
  data to be displayed in the view or the view retrieve the data from 
  presenter/view-model and  display it

2) How both presenter and view-model differ from each other.
   "**The MVVM uses databinding to update the view whereas the presenter uses 
    traditional methods to update the view**". Is it?

Answer (score 11):

In MVP, the Presenter holds a reference to a View, usually via interfaces.
When the Presenter computes new data, it is him who is responsible to call the right method on the View/Interface to update the UI.

In MVVM, the ViewModel "simply exposes" data (usually via LiveData or Rx) so it can be *observed*. It is not responsible for who is observing the data, and what is done with it. The view then observes that said data in the ViewModel, and updates its UI when the data changes.

To have a complete understanding of the differences between MVC, MVP and MVVM, I'd suggest to look at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrbhPcbZv0I

Comment: so in MVP the presenter update the view while in MVVM the view is responsible for updating the view by fetching data from view-model. Am i correct?

Comment: Well, in both scenarios, the view (Activity, Fragment etc) is responsible for updating the views (setText for example). However, the difference resides in the communication between View and Presenter/ViewModel. Presenter holds a reference to the View, and tells it to update. ViewModel exposes data (so does *not* references the view), and the View decides what to do with the observed data when it changes

Comment: Yeah got it. Any simple example on  mvp and mvvm.Like simple person details on both mvvm and mvp pattern